# Google Maps does not provide map after updating Android app target SDk and Gradle

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I developed an application that uses Google Maps for Android to show the map and route based on a GeoJSON file. The application was working fine until I decided to change some features of the project. At first step, I changed the target SDK version from 23 to 25, Android tools from 1.2 to 3 and Gradle from 2.1 to 4. But with these small changes, the GM just shows the "Google" logo in the fragment but not the map. In AS the logcat gives me this error:

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                           API Key: ---- I removed it intentionally ----
```

This is my AndroidManifest which you can see V2 is enabled.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

For the second possible reason, I checked Google credential and API key was valid too. How can I resolve this weird issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem as my current API key was application restricted, I create another credential and get another API key and it works fine.